# Fecthing information from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I really got a problem now. I tried for decades and I can't find why it is not working. I want to get the user that is logged in to see their email on a specific page. I tried a new code now and i get this error:     `Notice: Undefined variable: row in`

The code I use is:

```
  <?
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "select * from users where username=" . $username . ""; 
echo $sql;

$query = mysql_query($sql); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

}
?>
```

AND

```
<?php echo $row['email']; ?>
```

Comment: have you tried to manually run the query by doing `echo` ?

Comment: obligatory comment: `mysql` is deprecated. please use `mysqli`.

Comment: For how many decades have you been trying?

Comment: Is that echo line INSIDE the for loop?

Comment: Thanks for helping guys. The echo is not inside

Comment: Well then thats is porbably the issue @carl... At the least that is only going to echo the last result read by the loop, and at worst you may have that echo somewhere where `$row` isnt defined which is what seems to be happening here... where exactly do you try to echo the row??

Comment: you're assuming the query succeeded. At bare mininum, you should have `$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`. Never assume success when dealing with a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query = mysql_query("select * from users where username='".$username."'"); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $email=$row["email"];
    }
    echo $email;
 ?>
```

try this.
don't use mysql_* functions

Answer (score 0):

I think... Problem is in SQL query. I propose your column "username" is something like VARCHAR(50). So you have to add quote.

```
$sql = "select * from users where username='" . $username . "'";
```

Comment: Two things. First, if you can embed, than embed. It looks less like spaghetti code: -- $sql = "select * from users where username='$username'" -- Second, you should always at least use addslashes() around whatever it is that you're sending into the DB, so that someone can't execute a query if they pass one in as the username. If you're using mysqli, than use their real_escape_string method.

Answer (score 0):

I see a bug, and a design problem.

You've designed your script so that you're printing whatever was last assigned to $row in the condition of your while loop.

You're getting the error because the query is not returning anything and the loop is not running. Therefore, $row is never assigned. That being said, you probably don't want to use a while-loop if all you're trying to do is display the value of the "email" column in the first record returned. If you did want to, then stop it.

Call mysql_fetch_assoc() on your $result (doesn't return as much data), and check that it doesn't return FALSE (one or more records weren't found).

```
if((row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) === false)
    die("Error.");
```

?>
Email: